# Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document' with selector name contains dollar mark

Tags: javascript

Open Dev Tools with F12 in chrome and run code below, then get error.
Selector name is generate by framework, I wonder to get DOM selector name invalid rule.

```
document.querySelector("script[data-executed='true']#dxss_ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$cbpRVDetails$tabRVDetails$General1$ebGeneralReceivedByScript")
```

Comment: Pretty sure `id`s cannot contain dollar signs like that.

Comment: The question is not clear

Comment: I'm sure it's been asked before but the linked question seems to ask something different (`getElementByid` expects an ID and `querySelector` expects a CSS selector).

Comment: [selector name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors#Selectors) and [Selector syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/selector.html#selector-syntax)       
The selector methods accept one or more comma-separated selectors to determine what element or elements should be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Parameters) `$` with `\` to handle it as literal `$` in a CSS selector and you need to escape `\` with `\` to handle it as literal `\` in a JavaScript string:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("#foo\\$bar"));
```

```html
<div id="foo$bar"></div>
```